Select posts using @wordpress/data with query based on custom field always returns all records
I am trying to select records that have a custom field value that matches a search condition but the result is always all records
To register the custom field for my post type I am using the following code
register_post_meta(
  'my_post_type',
  'my_data',
  array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'single' => true,
    'type' => 'integer',
  )
)

To query the posts:
const data = useSelect((select) => {
  const metaQuery = [
    {
      key: 'my_data',
      value: [50, 100],
      compare: 'BETWEEN',
      type: 'NUMERIC'
    }
  ];
  return select(coreDataStore).getEntityRecords('postType', 'my_post_type', { meta_query: metaQuery });
});

but I am always receiving all records with my custom posts and zero errors or warnings. The metadata field is presented in the results. Generated request to the server contains the meta_query part, but it is url encoded. This is probably a reason why meta_query is ignored.
What did I miss?

while not the solution to this specific question, you may want to register a taxonomy that has bucketed terms e.g. 50-100 then assign those terms automatically in PHP. meta_query has very poor performance and doesn't scale with traffic or post count getting significantly slower/heavier on the database, which is why categories/tags/taxonomies aren't stored as post meta. That doesn't mean you have to give up storing precise integers in meta, but storing buckets in a taxonomy gives you the best of both worlds ( and it's easier to query the taxonomy in WP Data too )

@TomJNowell Good advice. This is my "plan B" )
